# Show UnVisibleForm when combination of key pressed

Tags: c#

i have created simple windows application.
when it runs i set its Visible property to false;
And now i want to make it Visible when conbination of keys pressed with

Comment: It could indeed be closed as a duplicate of that, but the accepted answer there is not the way to go. The other answer by Thomas Levesque there is a good one though.

Comment: @John Koerner, yout link helped me. there i foud it http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207 . sample works great. Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create [Keyboard Hook](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C). As noticed in the article, there is a very usefull project [on the CodePlex](http://globalmousekeyhook.codeplex.com/) that you can use to solve your issue.

Comment: A keyboard hook is probably overkill, and suffers from the "what if two programs did this?" problem: depending on what you do, either multiple programs react to the same key press, or your program silently breaks the other program. `RegisterHotkey` is the way to go instead, it gives an error if a program attempts to register a hotkey that is already registered, allowing you to choose a different one instead.

Comment: @hvd right, `RegisterHotkey` looks even more suitable for such cases

Comment: RegisterHotkey doesn't work in a console mode app, a message loop is required.

Comment: @HansPassant oh, thanks! I and hvd did not know about it! will know!

Comment: @HansPassant There's no reason why a console mode application can't have a message loop.

Comment: as i said, i converted application from console to windows. not RegisterHotkey do all for me